# Required boolean, found int?

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I'm still learning Java....

My task is to write a program which divides two doubles, but before it displays result of dividing, it has to say if they are dividible or not (without a rest). I HAVE TO use ternary operator.

code:

```
public class exercise {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double x = 8.4;
        double y = 4.2;
        double z = (int)(x % y);
        String result = (z>0) ? "not dividible" : "dividible";
        System.out.println("This operation is: " + result);
        System.out.println("The result of dividing is: " + (x/y));


    }



}
```

Compiler says for the line "String result = (z>0) ?....." that it requires boolean, and that it found int. Of course, compilation failed.

Comment: That line did *not* generate that error. The code *does* have at least one other error though (and would result in a *different* error message), which makes me suspect it's not the *actual* code.

Comment: Code works fine except you missed a bracket in last sysout statement

Comment: I added missing bracket, thanks for the tip. But it still doesn't compile....It points me to (z>0), says ';' error expected.

Comment: Post the *actual* code and the *actual* error message that the question is about. Make sure the file is saved before you try to compile it and then *copy and paste* the code in question. StackOverflow is so busted that questions like this get any non-negative votes..

Comment: This question should be closed because .. the question does not contain actual code associated with the error(s) reported. Please stop treating SO as a compiler.

Comment: This is actual code. I don't know what you mean user 2864...

Comment: @jutreni Again: That line did *not* generate that error. Either #1 the error message is lying or; #2 the code is lying. There is no #3. There were at least *two different* compilation issues - and *neither* relate to "Compiler says .. that it requires boolean". This entire question is therefor based on false pretenses (even if accidental).

Comment: @user268... Sorry, I'm not trolling. I only wrote what the compiler told me. Please don't be so harsh on me. I'm still trying to understand basics. I use geany on Linux. Ok, I agree we can close this question. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've missed the last closing bracket (`)`) of this statement.

```
System.out.println("The result of dividing is: " + (x/y);
```

It should be:

```
System.out.println("The result of dividing is: " + (x/y));
                                                        ↑
```

All the other stuff compiles for me.

Comment: I'm in love with that ↑. I randomly edit posts and put it there hopefully it'll make sense. This time it worked.

Comment: While this is *an* error, it has nothing to do with the reported error.

Comment: @user2864740, that's correct. :)

Comment: Can you share the **actual** code you have? The above snippet compiles perfectly.

Comment: Now it compiles for me also. I don't know what the problem was, except bracket (I added it and it didn't compile). Thank you, everyone.

Comment: ok, I think I know what was wrong. And you are right user286... On my other computer I had float type, not double.

Answer (score 2):

My compiler says that you dont have last parenthesis ) in this line:

```
System.out.println("The result of dividing is: " + (x/y);
```

Try this:

```
System.out.println("The result of dividing is: " + (x/y));
```

It compiles for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the syntax error, due you have forgotten the last closing bracket () of the last system.out line.

```
System.out.println("The result of dividing is: " + (x/y);
```

Should be:

```
System.out.println("The result of dividing is: " + (x/y));
```

If you solve this, then there is no problem.